# png image being cropped when saved from base64_decode

Tags: php, base64

I'm trying to create an image in my server's uploads directory from base64 code sent from the client-side. Below's the code for same :

```
<?php
    $dataURI = $_REQUEST['dataURI'];

    $dataURI = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $dataURI);
    $dataURI = str_replace(' ', '+', $dataURI);

    $data = base64_decode($dataURI);

    // $filename = UPLOAD_DIR . uniqid() . '.png';
    $filename = UPLOAD_DIR . 'saved-image' . '.png';

    $status = file_put_contents($filename, $data);

?>
```

the image is successfully created, but for some reason the image is cropped to half(horizontally). Could anyone tell me , what's wrong with this ?

Below is the original and saved/created image :

Original Image

[image]

Created Image

[image]

Comment: Could be string length being truncated?

Comment: What @Luke said - how are you submitting it to the server? Don't use `$_REQUEST` - explicitly choose one of the methods, in this case make sure it's `$_POST` as it will have a higher limit.

Comment: Thanks. Will try it out and post here.

Comment: Didn't even spot `$_REQUEST`! Yes, only ever use explicit access to predefined global vars. Always design the path data will take through your code so that nothing unexpected can ever happen :)

Comment: @Emissary I replaced $_REQUEST with $_POST and checked that the post data sent in headers and checked out echoed the same from PHP and they are same. So don't think string truncate is the problem. Is there anything else I can try out ?

Comment: @ggauravr see Martin's answer below, run [`phpinfo()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php) and look for `post_max_size` - is your image larger than this value?

Comment: Did that. post_max_size is 8M and the content length of the base64 code that I'm posting from client is 64XXX which is far lesser than the max size.

Comment: @ggauravr There are quicker ways to save the image but I've tested your script and it does work (though I don't have the original dataURI) - I can only assume part of it is being truncated before it reaches your PHP script.  If this isn't on the server side (IE apache config) then it's on the client side.  What browser are you using, what is being used to submit the image?  Is it being processed by some javascript before it's sent?

Answer (score 1):

You are getting your data through an HTTP parameter. Those acutally are limited in size (e.g. the default for Apache is . This limit varies between webservers and usually can pe set in your server config.

Also note that PHP has a `post_max_size` in `php.ini` which by default is 2MB

Comment: @Martin.. Thanks for the information. But the limit in my php.ini file was found to be 8M.. will check out the apache config if any .

Answer (score 1):

You've probably got some encoding problems:

```
$dataURI = str_replace(' ', '+', $dataURI);
```

Looks like an attempt here to undo a replacement of `+` with  which happened somewhere -most likely it was urldecoded. The `/` forward slash character is also part of the base64 symbol set, and so I suspect whatever messed up your `+` symbols also messed those up too.

What I would do is carefully trace the origin of this data and observe the transformations that are made.

Comment: He does not undo the `+` but replace a white space with an `+`. see php.net: `mixed str_replace ( mixed $search , mixed $replace , mixed $subject [, int &$count ] )`

Comment: to put it another way: before this code executed, something replaced the base64 symbol '+' with a space - most likely some urldecoding. He's used str_replace to undo this, but without really exploring the deeper reason *why* this was necessary.

Comment: @PaulDixon .. as you said I didn't go deeper on why that was done.. was just learning stuffs and got that snippet from some blog. but toggling that line of code is not affecting the created image.

Answer (score 0):

Confirm you are writing to a text file and NOT to a database. I recently was switching back and forth attempting to troubleshoot this very issue.  It turned out that my database column type, which was set to `text` was not large enough to store the image.  My images were coming back looking just like yours.  I switched to `longtext` and that fixed my issue.